# Alternative/shorter ways to delete an object from a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I find myself needing to "inline-delete" objects from a Ruby array fairly often, and my code generally looks like this:

```
my_array.flatten.reject{ |a| a == 'stupid' }.yada.yada.reject{ |a| a == 'dumb' }
```

I would love to get rid of the block and just pass the rejection as an argument like the following, but this doesn't work in Ruby:

```
my_array.flatten.reject('stupid').yada.yada.reject('dumb')
```

Is there  method I am missing, or a better way to remove objects in-line?

Comment: It's made-up; just used as an example method (i.e http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Yada+yada+yada).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_array.flatten.-(['stupid']).yada.yada.-(['dumb'])
```

Comment: Ha ha! That's slightly odd looking, but definitely shorter and does the job.

Comment: I never would have thought of using the dot syntax to call `-`.  Nice trick.

Comment: @TopherFangio I think you could write your own method for this deletion, by *Monkey patching*...

Comment: Accepted since it's nice and short, but I'd still love to see some other solutions. Obviously, I could just add my own function to do this; I just wanted to know if there were any "fun" ways to do it :-)